# Does ncclient support ericsson devices?

Tags: ncclient

Does ncclient support ericsson devices?

As ericsson device supports netconf, can we use ncclient to connect to these devices? Also does it support both netconf RFCs?

Answer (score 1):

If the netconf RFC has been followed by any networking vendor device, client do support those devices. So Ericsson should also work fine. If you face any problem, raise an issue on our github repo.